# Yes/No with boolean or if/else?

Tags: java, boolean

I'm having issues creating a yes/no input in my program. I want the user to be able to input a y/n after the last print statement, but i'm not quite sure how I would implement it. I know it would most likely include a boolean or an if/else statement, but i'm not quite sure. Any help?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Person 
{
public static void main(String[]args) 
{

    int age;
    String name;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter in your age.");
    age = scan.nextInt();

        if (age >= 10 && age < 18) 
        {
            System.out.println("So you're a kid, huh?");
        } 

        else if (age < 10)
        {
            System.out.println("Nice try.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (age >= 18 && age <= 100)
        {
            System.out.println("So you're an adult, huh?");
        }
        else if (age > 100)
        {
            System.out.println("Nice try.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter in your name");
        name = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("So you're " + age + " years old and your name is " + name + "?");

        System.out.println("y/n");
        }
}
```

Comment: why not using the same technique that you use to get the name? You'll get a String and then test it as if it was a boolean (with the equals method)

Comment: you can ask for a (Y)es or (N)o user input.

Comment: I assume he is looking for a boolean from it and doesn't know how to get that

Comment: I mean i'd like for the user to be able to input a "Y" or a "N" and if it's a "Y", it goes on, if a "N", then it goes back up to the beginning.. which will require all of it to be in a boolean.. shit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String answer;
boolean yn;

System.out.println("y/n");
while (true) {
  answer = in.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
  if (answer.equals("y")) {
    yn = true;
    break;
  } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
    yn = false;
    break;
  } else {
     System.out.println("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Please answer y/n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you need?

```
String answer = in.nextLine()
Boolean yn = (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") ? true : false);
```

Or, you can use a shorter form:

```
Boolean yn = (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

If you meant something else please post a clarification.

Answer (score 2):

just add `boolean answer = in.nextLine().toLowerCase().startsWith("y");`

So basically it sets `answer` to true if you type anything that starts with `y`. false otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use `org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject()`, it will return true for 'Yes' & 'Y'

Answer (score 0):

You would read in a string and compare it to the literal "y". The comparison yields a boolean.

You can expand this to first checking if it's "y" or "n" and complain if it's neither or narrow it to accept other equivalents like "yes" and "no".

In any case, your boolean is achieved by comparing to a literal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
boolean answer = "y".equalsIgnoreCase(in.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do while loop` for this like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int age;
        String name;
        String input = "y";
        do {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter in your age.");
            age = scan.nextInt();

            if (age >= 10 && age < 18) {
                System.out.println("So you're a kid, huh?");
            }

            else if (age < 10) {
                System.out.println("Nice try.");
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (age >= 18 && age <= 100) {
                System.out.println("So you're an adult, huh?");
            } else if (age > 100) {
                System.out.println("Nice try.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter in your name");
            name = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println("So you're " + age
                    + " years old and your name is " + name + "?");

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("y/n");
            input = sc.nextLine();
        } while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this figured out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MuseumHours2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String day;
        boolean yn = true;
        boolean userContinue;
        String answer;

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);


        do {
            System.out.println("Hello, thank you for visiting the Museum 
    website. For what day would you like to check our hours of operation?");
            day = stdIn.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Is today a holiday? Enter y or n.");
            answer = stdIn.nextLine();
                if (answer.equals("y")) {
                    yn = true;
                } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
                    yn = false;
                } else { 
                    System.out.println("Sorry, I didn't understand. Please reply y or n.");
                }

            switch (day) {
            case "Monday":
                System.out.println("Closed.");
                break;

            case "Tuesday":
                if (yn) {
                    System.out.println("We are open from 1:00 to 4:00.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("We are open from 12:00 to 5:00.");
                }
                break;
            case "Wednesday":
                if (yn) {
                    System.out.println("We are open from 2:00 to 5:00.");
                } else { 
                    System.out.println("We are open from 1:00 to 6:00.");
                    break;
                }
            case "Thursday":
                System.out.println("Closed.");
                break;
                }
            System.out.println("Do you want to re-run the program? Type y or n.");
        } while (userContinue = "y".equalsIgnoreCase(stdIn.nextLine()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean yn;
        String ageq;

        System.out.println("Please enter your age: ");
        ageq = sc.next();

        System.out.println("You entered " + ageq + " is this correct?");
        System.out.println("y/n");
        OUTER:
        while (true) {
            ageq = sc.next().trim().toLowerCase();
            switch (ageq) {
                case "y":
                    yn = true;
                    break OUTER;
                case "n":
                    yn = false;
                    break OUTER;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Sorry, I didn't get that. Please enter y/n");
                    break;
            }
        }

  }
```