# Making a Y/N Condition work

Tags: java

I need help with a SIMPLE Y/N Condition for my program. I don't really get it to work as I want to.

Unfortunately all the other topics I find is very confusing. I'm a very novice student in programming.

I want a Y/N Condition that wont crash and is not CASE SENSITIVE. so if Y or y it goes back to another menu, if n and N is just stop the program and if anything else is typed in it will loop until the Y or N conditions are met.

This is what i wrote:

```
String input = ScanString.nextLine();

while (!"Y".equals(input) || !"y".equals(input) || !"N".equals(input) || !"n".equals(input)) {
    System.out.println("Please enter Y/N (Not case sensitive): ");
    input = ScanString.nextLine();
}

if ("Y".equals(input) || "y".equals(input)) {
    meny1();
} else if ("N".equals(input) || "n".equals(input)) {

}
```

When it runs, whatever I put in, it won't break the while loop.

Comment: You can obviously use any indentation you like in your own code, but it's a very good idea to use something consistent and easily-readable -- both for yourself, and when asking other people for help. I've formatted the code in your question for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yes/No with boolean or if/else?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927885/yes-no-with-boolean-or-if-else)

Comment: Your condition is always true, hence it keeps looping. You either want to use `!(condition1 || condition2)` or `(!condition1 && !condition2)`.  The first option is faster, because the evaluation of or-conditions stops as soon as one of them is true. (Not really a big deal for a simple problem as yours, though)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`while (!"Y".equals(input) || !"y".equals(input) ||...` means "keep looping while the input isn't 'Y' **or** the input isn't 'y' **or**...". By definition, one of those conditions will always be true.

The simplest way to do what you're looking for would be a case insensitive comparison, and an **and** (`&&`) rather than **or** operator:

```
while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
```

That means "keep looping while the input isn't 'Y' or 'y' **and** the input isn't 'N' or 'n'.

Or the same in Yoda-speak, since you were using Yoda-speak:

```
while (!"Y".equalsIgnoreCase(input) && !"N".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
```

Comment: +1.  This should really get the checkmark.  I often create strings out of the variable to make it more clear and referenced statically.  May be overkill in this case, but then you can do YES.equalsIgnoreCase(input)...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while (!("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) && !("N".equalsIgnoreCase(input))) {

}
```

Or

```
String[] validInputs = { "Y", "N" };
while(!Arrays.asList(validInputs).contains(input.toUpperCase())) {

}
```